# how to find link using find.byselector using text property of link

Tags: watin

we have a link <> linktext <>

How to identify it using Find.BySelector and using text of link like we do in selenium....

//a [contains (text (),'linktext')]

Answer (score 0):

To find a link by exact text:

```
myIE.Link(Find.ByText("my literal link text")).Click();
```

To find a link by "contains" text, one way is to do the same as above but have `Find.ByText(new Regex......());`